# Drawing a double headed LaTeX arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

To draw a LaTeX arrow I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [ultra thick, green!40!black, -latex'] (-.72,4.) -- +(-90:1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me the left arrow. To make it a double headed arrow, I use a node to fake the second head, which gives me the right double headed arrow.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [ultra thick, green, -latex'] (-.72,4.) node [minimum size=.8cm, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.26cm, path picture={\draw [ultra thick, green, solid, -latex'] (0,0) -- +(90:.4cm);}]{} -- +(-90:1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make a true LaTeX double headed arrow without the use of the node to fake the second head?

Comment: Why don't you use `latex'-latex'` ?

Comment: Thank you. I tried -latex' -latex' which gave me an error, I did not know that I have to omit the first -

Comment: `-` in arrows definitions represents the arrow line, while `<` or `>`, or whatever style, define the kind of tip and position: `<->` two sided arrow, `->` from left to right, `<-` from right to left.

Comment: I came here via Google, but was having problems applying these suggestions. But @Ignasi 's comment I think shows the simplest way: ```\draw [<->] (-1/3,2/3) -- (-1/3,4/3);``` I found it on page 41-42 (section 2.17) of the PGF manual (https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) that @BambOo mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To provide a complete answer :

You can use the `latex'-latex'` style definition.

More documentation is available on arrows definition at section 16.2 page 182 of the [`pgf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will read this section thoroughly.

Comment: How does one do curved arrows with latex-latex?

Comment: @user3236841 I you have another question, please create a new post, otherwise you may receive little attention. In the meantime, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508135/why-is-the-bounding-box-not-updated-when-using-arrows-meta-arrowheads-in-inline. Where multiple bent arrows are shown (one of my own questions, maybe not the best example).

Answer (score 23):

I hope this helps:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw[>=triangle 45, <->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which shall give you

[image]

***Extra***

You could choose to play probably play with `\draw[>=style options, <->, color options] (0,0) -- (2,0);`

[image]