# Why is the bounding box not updated when using arrows.meta arrowheads in inline tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, bounding-box

I am using inline `tikz` calls to create annotations in my documents.

I am using the (below defined) `\Curve` macro to annotate graph plots (e.g. created with `pgfplots`) and `\Curvee` macro for more general drawings that could be bent, hence the use of `to path` instead of `-- path`. I manage to align the contents of the `\tikz` call using the `baseline` option and some `current bounding box` properties.

However, when using `bend ...` or `in=...,out=...` options to the `to path`, empty space is left inside the bounding box. 
When `-stealth` arrows are used there are also some discrepancies in the bounding box. Note that a `-Stealth` arrow updates the bounding box very well.

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393524/141947) it is said that the arrrows for the `arrows.meta` library should update the bounding box (while previous arrows could not).

So I have two questions actually :

- Why do the `stealth` arrows no update the bounding box correctly ? (I thought they were just `-Stealth` arrows with some default settings, but maybe not)
- Why is there an empty space in the bounding box of `to path` wiht `in=...,out=...` options ? (probably because of some construction nodes but if someone can explain...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\Curve{ m O{} }{%
    (%
    \tikz[baseline=(ref.base)] {%
        \draw[#1] plot coordinates {(0,0)} -- plot[#2] coordinates {(2mm,0)} -- plot coordinates {(4mm,0)};%
        \draw[] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \coordinate[yshift=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2] (ref) at (current bounding box.center);
    }%
    )%
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\Curvee{ m O{} }{%
    (%
    \tikz[baseline=(ref.base)] {%
        \draw[#1] (0,0) to[#2] (4mm,0mm);%
        \draw[] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \coordinate[yshift=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2] (ref) at (current bounding box.center);
    }%
    )%
}

\begin{document}
$1$
\Curve{red,-stealth}
\Curve{red,->}
\Curvee{red,-stealth,bend left}
\Curvee{red,->,bend left}
\Curvee{red,-stealth}[out=-60,in=150]
\Curvee{red,-Stealth}[out=-60,in=150]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The bounding box of spline curves contains the control points. Don't use `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, but prefer `\NewDocumentCommand`, so you'll be warned if you're trying to define an existing command.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for the tip on `NewDocumentCommand`, in general my personal macros are in french so overriding is not that common ^^. Regarding the controls points, that's what I thought at first, but the `bend left` actually defines `in=...,out=...` settings and does not leave so much space.  Any idea regarding the `stealth` arrows ?

Comment: @egreg, Ok my comment about `bend left` is idiotic, for sure with a two-sloped curve, the control points will be farther from the center. Sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [question of getting a tight bounding box for Bezier curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43621) is a repeating one, and, as egreg mentions, in Ti*k*Z the bounding box of a Bezier curve is taken to be the [minimal box that contains its control points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43624). In general, this yields a too generous bounding box. If you download the **experimental** library`tikzlibrarybbox.code.tex` from [here](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/bbox/tikzlibrarybbox.code.tex) (with the explanations being available [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501154)), you can solve the problem for the arrow heads from `arrows.meta`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,bending,bbox}
\newcommand\Curvee[2][]{%
    (%
    \tikz[baseline=(ref.base)] {%
     \begin{scope}[bezier bounding box]
        \draw[#2] (0,0) to[#1] (4mm,0mm);%
        \draw[] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \coordinate[yshift=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2] (ref) at (current bounding box.center);
      \end{scope}   
    }%
    )%
}

\begin{document}
$1$
\Curvee[bend left]{red,-Stealth}
\Curvee[out=-60,in=150]{red,-Stealth}
\Curvee[out=-60,in=150]{red,-Stealth}

$2$
\Curvee[bend left]{red,-{Stealth[bend]}}
\Curvee[out=-60,in=150]{red,-{Stealth[bend]}}
\Curvee[out=-60,in=150]{red,-{Stealth[bend]}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also loaded the `bending` library and bent the last three arrows. Notice that `bending` improves the arrow heads already when you only load the library, i.e. even if you do not add `bend` to the corresponding arrow options.